# Is there a way to import a csv file containing MGRS coordinates into winTAK?

Tags: csv

Im trying to import a file into wintak with MGRS coordinates. I have tried many times on a csv file just inputting the MGRS coordinates in different ways but each give me an import error. I could type the MGRS coordinates manually but im hoping to be able to do it by importing a file to make it as faster process. Thanks!

Already attempted CSV, PDF and seems like nothing works.